# Sending an Array through for loop using MPI_Send

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I am new at MPI,

I am trying to send data using MPI_Send function and Recv function. Node 0  accepts a number input and read a .dat file, and the rest of the nodes, defined at execution, counts the frequency (number of times it appears) in a .dat file. I had trouble trying to split the array, as it is not assigning the correct values. Can anyone guide me how to do this? I get random garbage numbers in the sendData array. Can something like this be implemented easier using MPI_Bcast?

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int send();
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int input, m, npes, myrank, newComm, data[1000];
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &npes);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
        int divideArray = 1000/npes;
        int sendData[divideArray];
        int z;
        int count = 0;
        if(myrank == 0)
        {
                FILE *file = fopen("input1.dat", "r");
                int i=0;
                int num, input;
                while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0)
                {
                        data[i] = num;
                        i++;
                }
                int  j, k;
                printf("Enter the number to find (1 to 100) : \n");
                scanf("%d", &input);
                //MPI_Bcast(&input, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                for(m = 0; m < npes; m++)
                {
                        //printf("Dataset %d: \n", m + 1);
                        for(k = divideArray * m; k < divideArray * (m+1);  k++)
                        {
                                //printf("%d\n", data[k]);
                                int counter = 0;
                                sendData[counter++] += data[k];
                                printf("%d\n", sendData[k]);
                                //MPI_Send(&value, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        }
                        printf("%d\n", sendData[m]);
                        MPI_Send(&sendData, 250, MPI_INT, m, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        MPI_Send(&input, 1, MPI_INT, m, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        //send();
                }
                //printf("The total frequency of %d is %d \n", input, count);
        }
        int zz;
        for(z = 1; z < npes; z++)
        {
                if(myrank == z)
                {
                        MPI_Recv(&sendData, 250, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
                        MPI_Recv(&input, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
                        for(zz = 0; zz < divideArray; zz++)
                        {
                                if(sendData[z] == input)
                                {
                                        count = count + 1;
                                        printf("Found One \n");
                                }
                        }
                        printf("My ID is %d and the frequency of %d is %d \n", myrank, input, count );
                }
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: The second loop is redundant. Only one iteration of all, namely the one with `z` equal to `myrank`, will do something useful. Also, to answer your last question - yes, this is a perfect candidate for being implemented with `MPI_Bcast` (for `input`) and with `MPI_Scatter`/`MPI_Scatterv` (for `sendData`). The random garbage is probably because you are always sending 250 elements instead of `1000/npes`.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me how to assign a specific range for each node to look at in the array to iterate? I'm still a little confuse how to work with the data when using broadcast function.

Comment: Please take a look at LLNL's [MPI tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Collective_Communication_Routines) and the more modern [MPI Tutorials](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/).